# Fill three numbers inside One number

Tags: math, arduino, numbers, protocols

I am trying to fit 3 numbers inside 1 number.But numbers will be only between 0 and 11.So their (base) is 12.For example i have 7,5,2 numbers.I come up with something like this:

```
Three numbers into One number :
7x12=84
84x5=420
420+2=422

Now getting back Three numbers from One number :
422 MOD 12 = 2 (the third number)
422 - 2 = 420
420 / 12 = 35
And i understanded that 35 is multiplication of first and the second number (i.e 7 and 5)
And now i cant get that 7 and 5 anyone knows how could i ???
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a pointless homework assignment.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You might have better luck on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'll echo "Why do you need to do this?"  You may want to just use base 16, since then it's hardcoded into just about every programming language.  And if this isn't programming related, then it's probably off-topic.

Comment: @Missy First of all i am programmer.And i need this because of protocol.I am sending some data from transmitter (like 3 numbers) and recieving it from reciever.But the problem is i can just send 1 number at time.So i didnt want to go this deep.Maybe you wouldnt understand :)

Comment: @Teepeemm I am not sure i understanded you.And this is programming related actually :)

Comment: @CoconutBandit I forgot to tag programming.Because this is programming related too actually.Thanks for that tip i will maybe post there too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I started typing this answer before the other one got posted, but this one is more specific to Arduino then the other one, so I'm leaving it)

## The code

You can use bit shifting to get multiple small numbers into one big number, in code it would look like this:

```
int a, b, c;

//putting then together
int big = (a << 8) + (b << 4) + c;

//separating them again
a = (big >> 8) & 15;
b = (big >> 4) & 15;
c = big & 15;
```

This code only works when a, b and c are all in the range [0, 15] witch appears to be enough for you case.

## How it works

The `>>` and `<<` operators are the bitshift operators, in short `a << n` shifts every bit in a by n places to the left, this is equivalent to multiplying by 2^n. Similarly, `a >> n` shifts to to the right. An example:

```
11 << 3 == 120    //0000 1011 -> 0101 1000
```

The `&` operator performs a bitwise and on the two operands:

```
6 & 5 == 4       //   0110
                 // & 0101
                 //-> 0100
```

These two operators are combined to "pack" and "unpack" the three numbers. For the packing every small number is shifted a bit to the left and they are all added together. This is how the bits of `big` now look (there are 16 of them because ints in Arduino are 16 bits wide):

```
    0000aaaabbbbcccc
```

When unpacking, the bits are shifted to the right again, and they are bitwise anded together with 15 to filter out any excess bits. This is what that last operation looks like to get b out again:

```
    00000000aaaabbbb    //big shifted 4 bits to the right
  & 0000000000001111    //anded together with 15
 -> 000000000000bbbb    //gives the original number b
```

Comment: Thanks, really good explanation, I just think there should be 15 where ever you used 16, right? Also since I am sending the number over nrf it can only use 8 bit int (byte), but it is impossible to put 3 numbers 0-15 in 1 byte I guess.

Comment: Yes, it should be 15 everywhere, edited that. Three numbers each in the range 0-15 need at least 12 bits, when they range 0-11 they need at least 11 bits. So no, you won't be able to pack them in one byte. The currently accepted answer wont work too in that case though.

Comment: The problem is i cannot accept 2 answers.Both of your answers are useful.Not solving my particular problem,but very useful.And i cant vote because i dont have 15 reputation.

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me wether my answer is accepted, I said it to make sure you knew what you asked is not possible.

Comment: Yes,my fault though :) Anyways i came up with another logic to solve my problem.Not really connected with maths :) Anyways thank you again,it is useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

All is working exactly like in base 10 (or 16). Here after your corrected example.

```
Three numbers into One number :
7x12^2=1008
5*12^1=60
2*12^0=2
1008+60+2=1070

Now getting back Three numbers from One number :
1070 MOD 12 = 2 (the third number)
1070/12 = 89 (integer division) => 89 MOD 12 = 5
89 / 12 = 7
```

Note also that the maximum value will be 11*12*12+11*12+11=1727.

If this is really programming related, you will be using 16bits instead of 3*8 bits so sparing one byte. An easyer method not using base 12 would be fit each number into half a byte (better code efficiency and same transmission length):

```
7<<(4+4) + 5<<4 + 2 = 1874

1874 & 0x000F = 2
1874>>4 & 0x000F = 5
1874>>8 & 0x0F = 7
```

Because MOD(12) and division by 12 is much less efficient than working with powers of 2

Comment: Thank you,this is really helpful  :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the principle of the [positional notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) to change from one or the other in any base

Treat yours numbers (n0,n1,...,nm) as a digit of a big number in the base B of your choosing so the new number is

```
N = n0*B^0 + n1*B^1 + ... + nm*B^m
```

to revert the process is also simple, while your number is greater than 0 find its modulo in respect to the base to get to get the first digit, then subtracts that digit and divide for the base, repeat until finish while saving each digit along the way

```
digit_list = []
while N > 0 do:
    d = N mod B
    N = (N - d) / B
    digit_list.append( d )
```

then if N is `N = n0*B^0 + n1*B^1 + ... + nm*B^m` doing `N mod B` give you n0, then subtract it leaving you with `n1*B^1 + ... + nm*B^m` and divide by B to reduce the exponents of all B and that is the new N, `N = n1*B^0 + ... + nm*B^(m-1)` repetition of that give you all the digit you start with

here is a working example in python

```
def compact_num( num_list, base=12 ):
    return sum( n*pow(base,i) for i,n in enumerate(num_list) )

def decompact_num( n, base=12):
    if n==0:
        return [0]
    result = []
    while n:
        n,d = divmod(n,base)
        result.append(d)
    return result
```

example

```
>>> compact_num([2,5,7])
1070
>>> decompact_num(1070)
[2, 5, 7]
>>> compact_num([10,2],16)
42
>>> decompact_num(42,16)
[10, 2]
>>>
```